# Getting Cache status for Azure CDN as 'UNCACHEABLE' while trying to serve files from Azure Data lake

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-cdn

Getting Cache status for Azure CDN as 'UNCACHEABLE' while trying to serve files from Azure Data lake.
How to ensure data lake response is being cached to CDN edge servers or remove the Cache-Control and Expires headers  for Data lake?

Comment: Need more info, like the entire request/response headers.

Comment: @RichardLi-MSFT : Sent a mail with entire request and response with header parameters as well